# Diff report bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I have a text file with lines saying:

```
File fileA and fileB differ 
File fileX and fileY differ
```

I need a bash script that goes through the whole file, for each line parses the file names and executes the command `diff fileA fileB > fileA.diff`

Comment: Good on you! Why does it have to be a bash script? Let us know which part of the solution you get stuck with and we'll endeavour to help. We won't do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command:

```
awk '/ differ$/ {print "diff "$2" "$4" >"$2".diff"}{}'
```

will give you a script you can run to do this.

See the following transcript:

```
pax$ echo 'File fileA and fileB differ
hello
File fileX and fileY differ' | awk '
    / differ$/ {print "diff "$2" "$4" >"$2".diff"}{}'
diff fileA fileB >fileA.diff
diff fileX fileY >fileX.diff
```

Capture the output, then run it with `bash` and you'll have what you need.

Note that this won't work well with filenames that have spaces in them - if you have such heinous beasts, you will need to do a little more intelligent parsing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now using this: while read line; do awk '/ differ$/ {print "diff "$2" "$4" > "$2".diff"}{}'; done < diffs.txt  Problem is awk only prints the command... how do I tell it to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

This command generates a list of diff commands:

```
[me@home]$ sed -n 's/File \(.*\) and \(.*\) differ/diff "\1" "\2" > "\1.diff"/p' infile
diff "fileA" "fileB" > "fileA.diff"
diff "fileX" "fileY" > "fileX.diff"
```

You can execute the generated commands by passing them to `bash` using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

```
[me@home]$ bash <(sed -n 's/File \(.*\) and \(.*\) differ/diff "\1" "\2" > "\1.diff"/p' infile )
```