# Execute awk output

Tags: bash, unix, awk

```
while read line;
do
  awk '/ differ$/ {print "diff "$2" "$4" > "$2".diff"}{}';
done < diffs.txt
```

This prints the command exactly as I want it. How do I tell it to execute the command?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483147/diff-report-bash-script/7483278#7483278) to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483147/diff-report-bash-script/7483213#7483213) tells you how to do it using Bash's process substitution. Did that not work for you? What happened?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`| bash` does the trick...

```
while read line;
do
  awk '/ differ$/ {print "diff "$2" "$4" > "$2".diff"}{}' | bash;
done < diffs.txt
```

Comment: Unless the script is specifically a Bash script you might as well use `sh`. Also I would put the pipe after `done` for reasons of both economy and understandability.

Comment: Actually the `while` loop is unnecessary, too. `awk '/ differ$/ {printf("diff \"%s\" \"%s\" > \"$2\".diff", $2,$4,$2)}' diffs.txt | sh`

Comment: actually the pipe to sh is unnecessary too :)

Comment: This does not work if the awk output is a command that wants its own terminal or pseudo terminal. like an ssh or tmux new.

Comment: Does not work for `export` either (use the @iankit solution with `$(.)`)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the  "system" command for these kinds of tasks.

```
awk '/ differ$/ {system("diff "$2" "$4" > "$2".diff")} diffs.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer (by @micheal) for this question is only partially correct. It works for almost all cases, except when the command requires creation of a new terminal or pseudo terminal. Like 'ssh' commands, or 'tmux new'..

Following code works for those cases also.

```
while read line;
do

  $(awk '/ differ$/ {print "diff "$2" "$4" > "$2".diff"}{}')
done < diffs.txt
```

$() is the bash command substitution pattern. You can read more about command substitution in Linux Documentation Project here : http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html.

Comment: This is also useful when the command must be executed in the same bash instance to be effective, e.g. when `export`-ing env. variables.